# Connecting 2 elements in a list

Tags: python, sorting

I have a function that takes an argument 'i' and returns 'a'.

'a' is placed in a list with list.append(a) and 'i' changes value (i is in a for-loop).

I later want to sort the list from largest to smallest, and be able to print out this sorted list, and for every 'a' printed, I want the corresponding 'i' aswell.

I thought about putting 'i' in a list aswell and "copying" the sorting order of the 'a'-list. But have no idea is this is a good way, or if it can even be done.

How do I sort the list containing values of 'a' and keep each 'a' connected to it's unique 'i'? So if I want to find which value of 'i' gave the 3rd largest 'a', I can do so.
edit: code looks like this (kind of)

```
for i in range(1, 100):
    a = function(i)
    list.append(a)
list.sort   #highest value of a first
print("Highest value of a was" + list[0] + "given by i:" + <i that produced list[0]>
```

Comment: Please post some code to at least start the problem. Perhaps you could create tuples and sort that list of tuples but from your description it's hard to grasp properly.

Comment: Perhaps instead of `list.append(a)` do `list.append((a,i))` so that you keep a and i together and only filter out i when you no longer need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *list comprehension* to keep the result and the input associated in a tuple.

```
# Apply the function to desired number range using a list comprehension
results = [(function(i), i) for i in range(1, 100)]
# Sort by the first element of each tuple, from largest to smallest
results = sorted(results, key=lambda t: t[0], reverse=True)
# Use a string formatting operation to display result
print("Highest value of a was {0} given by i: {1}".format(results[0][0],  results[0][1]))
```

- Documentation links for list comprehensions: [python2](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), [python3](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
- Documentation for `sorted`: [python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted), [python3](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#sorted)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class to put your list items in and pass a key to the sort function so it knows how to sort your list:

```
class ListItem():

  def __init__(self, value, index):
    self.value = value
    self.index = index


item1 = ListItem('test1', 1)
item2 = ListItem('test2', 2)
item3 = ListItem('test3', 3)

unsortedList = [item2, item3, item1]
unsortedList.sort(key = lambda item: item.index)

for item in unsortedList:
  print('index: ' + str(item.value) + ', value: ' + str(item.index))
```

Output:

> ```
> Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
> [GCC 4.8.2] on linux
>
> index: test1, value: 1
> index: test2, value: 2
> index: test3, value: 3
> ```